# How to install back the npm module in Node.js

Tags: node.js, powershell, npm, npm-install

Today, I wanted to download [a module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-red-contrib-mihome) via NPM.
Thought, because Node.js can't find the NPM modules that I install, maybe, I need to run NPM via the admin PowerShell, in the folder `C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules`. So, did it, ran the command:

```
npm i node-red-contrib-mihome
```

Somehow, it worked, but then, any other NPM installation did not start. That was because of this error:

```
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:936
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}

Node.js v17.2.0
```

Now, I don't have the `npm` module inside the `node_modules` folder.
How to get it back?

Comment: reinstall node js and verify node and npm are install.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you, [@Anis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6316804/anis), for the answer.

1. Run the Node.js installer (if you haven't deleted it)
2. Click `Next`, then `Repair`.
   [image: Node.js Setup]
3. Then, click `Repair` again and wait
4. Click `Finish`
   Now you should have the `C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm` module.

Answer (score 1):

way1:
Download node (zip format) from the node.js official website, extract it and copy it to the node file. Enter npm update at the terminal.

way2:
Set environment variables

```
SET PATH=C:\Program Files\Nodejs;%PATH%
```